# MGF of discrete random variable - simplification of series?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, summation

I want to find the moment-generating function of a discrete random variable $X$ with probability mass function $p_X(x)=\frac{2}{3^{x+1}}$ for $x \in \{1,2,3...\}$

For discrete random variables, $M_x(t) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} e^{tx}p_X(x)$

Thus, for my problem, $M_x(t)= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{tx}}{3^{x+1}}$

My question is: can this series be simplified at all? My typical strategy in such situations is to use properties of Taylor series (e.g., $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$), but I do not see any obvious candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given series is $$2/3* \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(\frac{e^t}{3}})^n$$This is a geometric series and also in the form of the example provided in the question. (Just put x = $\frac{e^t}{3}$)